# How to launch Java app on certain monitor?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, java

I have laptop with external monitor connected, so actually I have two displays (with different resolutions, but I guess resolution does not matters).

When I launch Java app (Supermicro IPMIView in my case), it seems that the app tries to calculate dimensions and place itself to some central area of a screen. In fact I see app window splitted to 2 parts - one on the first monitor and one on the second. This problem appears with Java applications only.

Could I somehow force Java to place its window on certain monitor (or, let's say on any monitor, but on one monitor only at the same time)?

Application starts by execution of shell-script, which checks a lot off stuff in environment, and, on the end, evals the code `./jre/bin/java com.zerog.lax.LAX /path/to/IPMIView20.lax /tmp/env.properties.12345`

I use Kubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Looks like developer needs to update the software

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xdotool` to change the window position and size after it has popped up. Perhaps something like

```
xdotool search --name "Supermicro IPMIView" windowsize 800 600
xdotool search --name "Supermicro IPMIView" windowmove 10 10
```

You can also set up `devilspie` as a daemon that does this automagically. See eg [Ubuntu documentation on Devilspie](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can't. If the developer of the application just used a fixed possition or hardcoded "display 0" (sounds like that's the case from what you describe) then it's just there. This is not Java specific. It sounds like crappy programming to me.

I got quite alot Java apps and a dual monitor setup as well and I only got this issue only for apps that have the possition hardcoded in them (same happens to .Net applications or whatever lang. / framework you want to use, if the programmer hardcoded the possition)